# Tietze extension theorem for lower semi continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

On the Tietze extension theorem, if instead of a continuous function "f" we use a lower semi continuous function on a closed subspace of a metric space, is the theorem correct? I mean, can we extend every lower semi continuous function from a closed subspace of a metric space to the space?

Comment: Yes, at least for bounded functions. A function is lower-semicontinuous iff it is the pointwise supremum of a family of continuous functions. Just extend each continuous function in the family and take the pointwise supremum.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: If the function $f$ is bounded above, say $f \le M$, then one can simply extend the function by letting it equal $M$ on the complement of our closed set $E$.  If you allow the extended reals, you could also set $f = +\infty$ on $E^c$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point.